# Что не так с моим интерфейсом MySupplier<T>?

Tags: java, функции

В чём разница между стандартным типом [`java.util.function.Supplier<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html)  и написанным мной:

```java
@FunctionalInterface
interface MySupplier<T> {
    T get();
}
```

В этой программе функции `works` и `fails` отличаются только типом, к которому приводится `Main::prompt`, но первая работает, а вторая говорит `TypeError: prompt is not a function`:
[tio.run](https://tio.run/##vVLLTsMwELznKxafHAT@gJZUCKkIDuWSShwQB5O6waljW/YmbYX67SEPB7WocIOT7dmZ3Z2RC17z62K1aRpZWuMQihZgFUrF1pXOUBrNLqfRUXHHfOakxW8wk6ZDotv7IOPqUaNwa56JSI43WOzTylolhbtZzuAjAlhCLpDG0@gQRbZ6UzKDTHHvYcGl7hkB9cixPWojV1C2NZqikzp/eQXuch8Dvjuz9TDfZcJ2C/RagHTvUZTMVMhsy0elKUmSBLbGbTy0N9LO7og90C3yq2zNpTqR9QDtH4dOerxmaPnTajV3IHQutYAEtNhC2ic776EF1zwXjsaszWeA7vZPvBSUFH4cPqiZrZAS60xpkVwB/Yp4SGgWd1FOJgMhKM/4C81EzdXYjcYkPm8t2P5va0f/52/MDV1hZAQ7TmDlNJAHoZSBZ@PU6oIM0kPTfAI)

```java
import java.util.function.*;
import javax.script.*;
import java.io.*;
    
@FunctionalInterface
interface MySupplier<T> {
    T get();
}
    
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("=== works ===");
        works();
    
        System.out.println("=== fails ===");
        fails();
    }
    
    static void works() throws Exception {
        var engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("js");
        engine.put("prompt", (Supplier<String>)Main::prompt);
        System.out.println(engine.eval("prompt()"));
    }
    
    static void fails() throws Exception {
        var engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("js");
        engine.put("prompt", (MySupplier<String>)Main::prompt);
        System.out.println(engine.eval("prompt()"));
    }
    
    static String prompt() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Не знаю причину еще, но похоже, что проблема в том, что интерфейс `MySupplier` не public

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Любой класс/интерфейс, который используется внутри js движка должен быть публичным для того, чтоб движок мог его использовать.

Для вызова методов движок использует рефлексию. Схематически и упрощенно то, как это происходит можно показать на примере:

```
// Main.java 
package main;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

import otherpackage.EngineFromOtherPackage;

@FunctionalInterface
interface MySupplier<T> {
  T get();
}

public class Main {
 
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("=== works ===");
    works();

    System.out.println("=== fails ===");
    fails();
  }

  static void works() throws Exception {
    var engine = new EngineFromOtherPackage();
    engine.use((Supplier<String>)Main::prompt);
  }

  static void fails() throws Exception {
    var engine = new EngineFromOtherPackage();
    engine.use((MySupplier<String>)Main::prompt);
  }

  static String prompt() {
    return "Hello World!";
  }
}

// EngineFromOtherPackage.java
package otherpackage;
public class EngineFromOtherPackage {

  public void use(Object f) {
    Method method;
    try {
      method = f.getClass().getInterfaces()[0].getDeclaredMethod("get");
      method.invoke(f, null);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
    
}
```

Если запустить этот код, то получим исключение `IllegalAccessException` при попытке вызвать метод из класса `MySupplier`, так как он package-private и значит не доступен из класса js движка, который естественно находися в своем пакете.

На этапе связывания методов (т.е. когда для функции скрипта ищется ее реализация) в движке [делается проверка](https://code.googlesource.com/edge/openjdk/+/refs/heads/jdk8u111-b14/nashorn/src/jdk/nashorn/internal/runtime/linker/NashornBeansLinker.java#172) прав доступа и сообщение об ошибке (по задумке более дружелюбное пользователю) говорит, что функция не найдена, так как она по сути недоступна для вызова (хотя и существует если [обойти права доступа](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible(boolean))).

Может возникнуть вопрос: почему права доступа не обходятся, как это часто делается в фреймворках типа spring?

Можно поспекулировать на эту тему. Ключевой момент тут это то, что исполняемый код тут на скриптовом языке. Вообще в такого рода (скриптовых) движках есть большая проблема с обеспечением безопасности. Вот что пишет об этом [документация](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/nashorn/api.html#classfilter_introduction) по Nashorn, который используется в данном случае:

> Applications that embed Nashorn, in particular, server-side JavaScript frameworks, often have to run scripts from untrusted sources and therefore must limit access to Java APIs.

Тут речь идет об ограничении доступа даже к открытому API из JDK типа reflection API и т.д. То есть если, скажем, в spring вам нужно, чтоб spring вызвал методы или устанавливал значения даже приватных полей **ваших** же бинов, которые точно так же могут быть недоступны, то тут для скриптовых движков ситуация отличается, так как скрипт может быть получен от пользователя и нужно его ограничить.

Comment: Хм.. Почему-то мне казалось, что в рефлексии шарпа подобных фокусов нет, хотя не уверен.

Answer (score 2):

Нужно сделать интерфейс публичным: вынести его в файл `MySupplier.java` или хотя бы определить его внутри класса `Main`:

```java
public class Main {
    @FunctionalInterface
    public interface MySupplier<T> {
        T get();
    }
    // ...
}
```

Тогда его сможет обнаружить скриптовый движок:

```
=== works ===
Hello World!
=== fails ===
Hello World!
```

Comment: Держи плюсик, но если @Roman напишет ответ, то галочка его.

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA, ok, принял. Я просто по комментарию подумал, что ты собираешься ещё и причину найти - зачем там public нужен. А вообще, мог бы сразу ответом писать.